# List referencing entities using endpoints-proto-datastore

Tags: endpoints-proto-datastore

If you have, say, an `EndpointsModel` class, Employee, which contains a reference to an `EndpointsModel` class, Company, how do you include a method in the `remote.Service` class CompanyService that lists its employees?

The question might better be phrased as" "How to access a query variable within a method?"

The path might look like so:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/contacts/v1/companies/123/employees
```

Here's `CompanyService::employees()`:

```py
@Employee.query_method(http_method='GET', path='companies/{id}/employees')
def employees(self, company):
    """
    Retrieve the employees for this company
    """
    company_key = ndb.Key(Company, company)
    return Employee.query(Employee.company == company_key).fetch(20)
```

When `company_key` is computed using a hardcoded value, say '123', This method actually works perfectly. But how to get the company id? In "query" methods, as opposed to "query_method" methods, this is simply an attribute of the model parameter with which the method is called. But there doesn't seem to be an easy way to extract the value from the `query` parameter with which a "query_method" method is called.

Since this is a central design feature of any API I would like to create, I really need to get it worked out. The engineering boilerplate comprising the EPD and endpoints libraries provide some good documentation in the comments but the code itself is above my pay grade :-)

Comment: Thinking about this some more, it occurs to me that `employees()` might better be a query method of `EmployeeService`. Then it is simply a matter of including the company key in the path: `employees/list?company="123"`. I just hesitate to use a query parameter when the path specified in the question is so elegant.

Comment: The above is, in fact, the way I implemented it. It's straightforward to just add `company_id` as a query parameter to `EmployeeService.list()`. Not as elegant as having the nice `companies/{id}/employees` path, but it will have to do.